# Card with wrapped text and row elements

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**I'm trying to achieve the following result:**

[image]

It's part of a ListView.builder and if the text is too long it overflows in the card.

So far this is what I've tried but I see a Overflow error and it doesn't go to a new line, looks like this:

[image]

```
Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
           children: <Widget>[
            const Icon(Icons.radio_button),
            const SizedBox(width: 8),
            Wrap(
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Some text that is too long so it overflows'),
                ],
            ),
            const Text('9'),
           ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I'm not sure of the purpose of your Row that only contains another row.

But the widget you are looking for is a flexible widget. As all of the other widgets have a defined size, the flexible widget will use up the remaining available space and wrap content appropriately.

```
Card(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    child: Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
         child: Row(
             children: <Widget>[
                const Icon(Icons.radio),
                const SizedBox(width: 8),
                const SizedBox(width: 8),
                Flexible(
                   child: 
                      Text(
                        'Some text that is too long so it really is too big and overflows'),),
                const Text('9'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: This worked once I added: 'fit: FlexFit.tight', as a property to the Flexible, otherwise shorter text was not aligned to the start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap text with `Flexible` and remove extra row

```
  Card(
         clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.radio),
                  const SizedBox(width: 8),
                  const SizedBox(width: 8),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Text(
                      'Some text that is too long so it overflows Some text that is too long so it overflows',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text('9'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```